# std::optional<T> assignment operators

Tags: c++17, assignment-operator, stdoptional

My reference is to options (4), (5) and (6) of [std::optional::operator=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator%3D)

Given the premise that

```
The class template std::optional manages an optional contained value, i.e. a value that may or may not be present.
```

(4)  from the link states in the description:

```
The function does not participate in overload resolution unless std::decay_t<U> (until C++20)std::remove_cvref_t<U> (since C++20) is not std::optional<T>, std::is_constructible_v<T, U> is true, std::is_assignable_v<T&, U> is true, and at least one of the following is true:

    T is not a scalar type;
    std::decay_t<U> is not T.
```

The implication above seems to be that `U` is not `std::optional<T>`, but since `std::optional<T>` *could be* `T`, how does this condition correlate to the other condition

```
std::is_constructible_v<T, U> is true, std::is_assignable_v<T&, U> is true
```

Also if `T` is not a scalar type, how can the assignment possibly work if `std::decay_t<U>` is not `T`?

(5) and (6) state

```
These overloads do not participate in overload resolution unless the following conditions are met:

    T is not constructible, convertible, or assignable from any expression of type (possibly const) std::optional<U>, i.e., the following 12 type traits are all false:
        std::is_constructible_v<T, std::optional<U>&>
        std::is_constructible_v<T, const std::optional<U>&>
        std::is_constructible_v<T, std::optional<U>&&>
        std::is_constructible_v<T, const std::optional<U>&&>
        std::is_convertible_v<std::optional<U>&, T>
        std::is_convertible_v<const std::optional<U>&, T>
        std::is_convertible_v<std::optional<U>&&, T>
        std::is_convertible_v<const std::optional<U>&&, T>
        std::is_assignable_v<T&, std::optional<U>&>
        std::is_assignable_v<T&, const std::optional<U>&>
        std::is_assignable_v<T&, std::optional<U>&&>
        std::is_assignable_v<T&, const std::optional<U>&&>.
```

Again, `std::optional<U>` *could be* `U`, and if so how does the assignment work?

The description further reads:

```
For overload (5), std::is_constructible_v<T, const U&> and std::is_assignable_v<T&, const U&> are both true.
For overload (6), std::is_constructible_v<T, U> and std::is_assignable_v<T&, U> are both true
```

Wouldn't this be the case if `std::optional<U>` were to contain `U`?

Should `std::optional<T>` and `std::optional<U>` be assumed have no valid values to resolve the above apparent contradictions?

Based on the test code below, `std::optional<T>` and `T` are distinct types.

```
#include<optional>
#include<type_traits>
#include<string>
#include<ios>
#include<iostream>

using std::optional;
using std::is_same;
using std::string;
using std::boolalpha;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main (){
  optional<string> opt("yes");
  string s("yeah"); 

  cout << boolalpha << is_same<decltype(opt),decltype(s)>::value << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show a code example that you think is suspicious under these rules.

Comment: You state that "`std::optional<T>` could be `T`" and further again that "`std::optional<U>` could be `U`", but these things are impossible. Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: added source code...indeed they are different types

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is. `std::optional<T>` and `T` are always distinct types. No test code is needed. Perhaps you don't realise that C++ types are static and cannot change when object values change?